# Convert to long table generating subvariables within a variable with tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

Convert to long by generating sub-variables within a variable  "Variable" colulum I group 1:2 = WW, 34 = MM, and 158:190=EE.

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("A", "B", "C"), `1`=c("1.9", "6.8", "4.7"), `2`=c("1.9", "6.8", "4.7"), `34`=c("3.9", "0.3", "2.7"), `158`=c("2.9", "3", "45"),`190`=c("22.1", "7.4", "56"), check.names=FALSE)
```

from my df:

```
  1     2   34   158   190
    
    A   1.9  1.9  3.9  2.9   22.1
    B   6.8  6.3  0.3  3     7.4
    C   4.7  4.7  2.7  45    56
```

Desired output

```
Letter  Number  Variable  Value
A         1        WW      1.9
A         2        WW      1.9
A         34       MM      3.9
A         158      EE      2.9
A         190      EE      22.1
B         1        WW      6.8
B         2        WW      6.8
B         34       MM      0.3
B         158      EE      3
B         190      EE      7.4 
...
```

I tried this but I need to add the new cathegory including MM, MM and EE.

```
library(tidyr)    
data_long <- gather(df, Letter, value, 1:90, factor_key=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = !A, names_to = 'Number', values_to = 'Value') %>% type.convert(as.is = T) %>% 
    mutate(Variable = case_when(Number %in% c(1,2) ~ 'WW', Number  == 34 ~ 'MM', TRUE ~ 'EE')) %>% 
   select('Letter' = A, Number, Variable, Value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 4
   Letter Number Variable Value
   <chr>   <int> <chr>    <dbl>
 1 A           1 WW         1.9
 2 A           2 WW         1.9
 3 A          34 MM         3.9
 4 A         158 EE         2.9
 5 A         190 EE        22.1
 6 B           1 WW         6.8
 7 B           2 WW         6.8
 8 B          34 MM         0.3
 9 B         158 EE         3  
10 B         190 EE         7.4
11 C           1 WW         4.7
12 C           2 WW         4.7
13 C          34 MM         2.7
14 C         158 EE        45  
15 C         190 EE        56  
>
```

Comment: I get the following error from running your script: Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function '%in%': object 'Number' not found

Comment: is this the version again? seems like a similar error to what I had on the other post.

Comment: could something like this work? defining all the columns? in my real data I have many number columns to subset into the variables
"%>% 
+   mutate(Variable = case_when(Number %in% c(1,2) ~ 'WW', Number %in% c(34) ~ 'MM', Number %in% c(158,190) ~ 'EE',,)) %>%"

Comment: Have you mentioned names_to = 'Number' in pivot_longer? If you did, can you please check if you used quotes surrounding it?

Comment: Yes I tried copying your code with the sample data I provided and it says this. Same this my data. Check edited pot I attached the screenshot of my code ta the end

Comment: Yes, and it also happens to my real data. heck the attached screenshot of my data code, I copied from here.

Comment: On my real dataset I have 17 "Numbers" / columns, I could do them manually using something like this? is still does not work though

mutate(Variable = case_when(grepl("1", 'Number') ~ 'WW',

Comment: @Ecg OK I get it, you need to remove the '+' signs at the begining of each line. I have updated my answer. Can you please check now.

Comment: @Ecg, regarding having 17 numbers columns, difficult to tell without looking at the data, but, if they can be clubbed as we did for columns with numbers 1,2, you won't have a big case_when, but if they are all stand alones like 34, then we need to hardcode it.

Comment: Perfect! That was it, silly mistake, useful to attach the code then, thanks a lot! :) good to be learning bits of coding and clubbing functions!

Comment: Sorry but for my data shows me the following error. I tried to change them all to character or to numeric (sample data are all character). But still it does not work. Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector. x Subscript has the wrong type `tbl_df< L4 : character 1344: character 1345: character 1365: character 1366: character 1367: character 1419: character 1420: character 1421: character 1473: character 1475: character 1528: character 1584: character 1585: character 1586: character 1678: character 1679: character 1680: character >`. ℹ It must be numeric or character. (L4=A)

Comment: Difficult to tell without looking at data, can you raise a question with same column structure and random data that's indicative of you actual data?